# How to replace selected blank cells of Column B with corresponding cells of a different column

Tags: excel, editing

How do I replace selected blank cells of Column B with corresponding data from a different column. This is a little bit of data management and mass-editing of data which I am working on.

If you don't understand my question, I will give an example:

I want to replace the selected, blank cell B4 with a corresponding cell from a different column that has text in it (E4); however, I want to do this all at once for a huge amount of selected blank cells in column B, and I want them replaced with the text from cells in the same row, but in a different column.

If someone could tell me how to do this it would be amazing!

Thanks!

Comment: You will need to use vba.

Comment: You could copy the data which is in column B to another column eg Z. Then do an if in column B to pick the data in Column Z if not blank and different cell if blank

Comment: @ScottCraner I don't think the wording "filled" is used for cell fill color, just for "filled with data", so this can be done without VBA. I edited the question to make that clearer

Comment: @teylyn True and if this is a one off your method is perfect, If not the OP can use the macro recorder to get a start on writing it in vba.  In truth, the vba I imagined followed your method, almost exactly.

Answer (score 2):

- Select column B
- hit the F5 key to open the Goto dialog (or use Ctrl-G)
- click the Special button
- Tick the "blank" option and hit OK
- now all blank cells in column B are selected and the first blank cell in column B has the focus
- without changing the selection, type a = sign, then use the arrow key to go to column E in the same row
- hold down the Ctrl key and hit Enter
- now all previously empty cells in column B contain the value from column E with a formula along the lines of `=E2`

[image]

You can copy column B and use paste special > values to replace the formulas with the results.